# multiprocessing and memory issues

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a script that reads a file with 700,000 or so lines. For each line it returns a list  of values it calculated from that line. Before I tried to use multiprocessing I was using a for loop and increment the values for each line to a global variable (because in the end I am after a sum). Unfortunately with the multiprocessing modules I cannot just add something to the global variable, because they are separate processes. Instead I had each process return the values I am after, and use Pool.map to create a huge list of the returned values. Then, I could loop through that list and get the sums I am after. This is very memory intensive. Any suggestions? I realize this is probably hard to read, so, I can clarify if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please clarify. Sounds to me like you could calculate the sums of the values in each process, and then one total at the end.   
But then again, I don't know enough about the specific problem to know for sure.

What you want is more or less a simple application of [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Comment: No, one of the things I am returning is a list, and so I want to sum the ith element of the list of each process.

Comment: Given that two of us haven't been able to fully understand what you want,  I think adding some code to your question would help to improve the chance you get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an accumulator in each process, then at the end add up all those accumulators. You only need to store one value per process.

Comment: Well I am taking multiple values from each process, then summing the values from the different processes. So how would I only have to return one value from each process if I need more than one variable from them?